# Python Requests API - No Results

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use a website's "search bar" by sending a get request to the url that the website would redirect me to when I search through their search bar.

Via the requests api, I am getting "no results" from the website. However, when I search directly through the website, I do obtain results. The url that my code generated and the url that the website redirects me to is the exact same, yet my code sees "no results."

Why does this happen? Is there a way to fix it?

Sample code:

```
    url = "https://songbpm.com/{}?q={}".format("shape-of-you-ed-sheeran", "shape%20of%20you%20ed%20sheeran")
    r = requests.get(url,  auth=('user', 'pass'))
    while r.status_code!=200:
        time.sleep(1)

    lines = r.content.decode("utf-8").split("<div class=\"media-content\">")
```

n
In this case, `lines` would just be a string, because the `split()` function was not able to split because it did not find a matching string. The string `<div class=\"media-content\">` would only be found only if the website returned results.

Comment: maybe when using the website, there is more involved like a javascript. please share some code snippet with us.

Comment: The `requests` module, at least how I have used it, returns results from an API. How exactly are you requesting results from this website? Showing your code is crucial to asking a good question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes show your code.

Comment: Also, try tracing what your broser sends to the website using e.g. Fiddler, and you will also see headers and cookies that may be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to write `url = "https://songbpm.com/{}?q={}".format(song_name, artist)`? I assume you have two variables called `song_name` and `artist` that you're trying to add to the URL using `format()`.

What you're doing right now is simply adding the strings `"song_name"` and `"artist"` and getting no results because no song exists called "song_name" by "artist."

For instance, the following code:

```
import requests
import time

song_name = 'thunderstruck'
artist = 'acdc'
url = "https://songbpm.com/{}?q={}".format(song_name, artist)
r = requests.get(url,  auth=('user', 'pass'))

lines = r.content.decode("utf-8").split("<div class=\"media-content\">") 
print(len(lines))
```

prints `6`, showing that it works as intended if you remove the quotes around `song_name` and `artist`.

Comment: Even replacing `song_name` and `artist` with the new values you edited in still gives me `6` as the result for `len(lines)`. Is something not working in your new example?